# How to get one column and select other column as horizontally

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Given data of the form...

```
+-------------+--------------+
| Employee_ID | Candidate_ID |
+-------------+--------------+
| 1000        | 1            |
| 1000        | 2            |
| 1000        | 5            |
| 1111        | 2            |
| 1111        | 5            |
+-------------+--------------+
```

...how can I use T-SQL to generate output of the form...

```
+-------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| Employee_ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |...|
+-------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1000        | 1 | 2 | 5 |   |  |
| 1111        | 2 |5  |   |   |  |
+-------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Look up pivot tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pivot table.
Below is the link for a similar question on stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

```
SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT id, ' +   @PivotColumns + 'FROM tablename
    PIVOT( SUM(id1) FOR id2 IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P WHERE cinditionid1=' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @cinditionid1) 
    + ' and cinditionid2=' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @cinditionid2) '
```

Notes-:
1.@PivotColumns  is the list of colums seperated by ','

2.PIVOT( SUM(id1) FOR id2 IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) is the condition on which you want to pivot the table

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It is very helpful.